# How do I change the edge length in sumo netedit?

Tags: xml, sumo

I tried changing the attribute in the inspect mode, however, while the value of the edge certainly gets set no changes appear visually.

I inspected the .xml file as well which showed the attribute to be changed. Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of length in SUMO networks. One is the geometrical length (for a straight edge this is the euclidean distance between start and end) and one is the loaded or assigned length. Both are independent (and usually both are equal) and if you change the attribute in netedit you only change the loaded length. To change the geometrical length you need to move at least one of the endpoints or change the geometry otherwise. The reason why there are two values is that the measured length of the road might deviate from the visual length. The easiest example is if the road has elevation differences while the network is only 2D.